# Integrity Error - Flask & SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my first time playing around with SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to just insert an item into a table and have flask print out that item. However, I keep on getting an integrity error like this when I don't catch the exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column email is not unique u'INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)' ('test', 'test@gmail.com')
```

I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % self.username

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return User.query.all() # I don't think this will work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    try:
        x = User("test", "test@gmail.com")
        db.session.add(x)
        db.session.commit()
        print "worked"
    except IntegrityError:
        print "Not Working"

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Would anyone mind giving a hand? I've done some research on IntegrityError but most of the documentation is on handling the error and not preventing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, the reason for this is a bit tricky :)

The error message does indeed mean that this email address is already in the DB. But why the heck is this? Because the `debug` flag tells the built-in server to also use the reloader. And this reloader basically makes the app run twice on the first start. You can see that in the output:

```
$ python2 server.py
worked
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
Not Working
```

There are multiple ways to get around that. Quick'n'dirty would be to just disable the reloader:

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

A better way would be to not populate the test DB that way. Instead you could create a separate custom command using [Flask's CLI](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/).

Comment: Flask-Script warning: While the maintainers are willing to merge PR’s, they are not actively developing features. As of Flask 0.11, Flask includes a built-in CLI tool, and that may fit your needs better.

Comment: @rla Thanks for pointing this out. Feel free to edit my answer or let me know, I can do it as well.